# iOS NSFetchedResultsController similar class for Realm version 2.1

Tags: ios, core-data, realm

I'm working with a project which has `Realm` database. I have update `Realm` to the latest version (2.1.1). I'm quite familiar with `CoreData` with NSFetchedResultController class to manage the tableview (We only need to manage the underlying data).

Is there any similar class or solution that work with the latest Realm version so that we can just manage the underlying data and the tableView will be automatically updated?

Comment: https://realm.io/news/migrating-from-core-data-to-realm/

Comment: Thanks but for the path NSfetchResultController similar class. Is there any native support or we need to use another library?

Comment: https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQFetchedResultsController. Realm is promoting you to use the above library.

Comment: notice there is a hints: Starting with v4.0 and Realm v0.99, RBQFetchedResultsController works automatically with Realm's fine-grained notification support. It is recommended to use Realm's API directly instead of RBQFetchedResultsController unless you need support for sections. so should we use fine-grained...?

Comment: Give the link please

Comment: hi just behind https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQFetchedResultsController. how it work!

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-notifications. Check the Collection Notification.

Comment: I don't believe Collection Notifications supports sections (as of now), so it doesn't seem like a good replacement for NSFetchedResultsController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent concept of `NSFetchedResultsController` in Realm is called ["Collection Notifications"](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications).

There's a blog post that just came out today with more information about the high level overview of architecting an app with Realm's Collection Notifications like that: [Live Objects and Fine-Grained Notifications: Updates with Realm](https://realm.io/news/live-objects-fine-grained-notifications-realm-update/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Will dig into the article. Realm is moving quite fast. what do you think the advantage of using Realm over CoreData?

Comment: These are my opinions, but ease of use, maintainability, performance, open source, cross-platform, sync features, "live objects", simpler threading model, native Swift API, timely support (). To name a few.

Comment: Seems like Collection Notifications doesn't have support for sections?

Comment: Correct. That feature is tracked in https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3384

Answer (score 0):

Two open source projects I know of that link Realm to the awesomeness that is `NSFetchedResultsController`:

1. https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQFetchedResultsController

   > Drop-in replacement for NSFetchedResultsController backed by Realm.
2. https://github.com/polqf/RealmResultsController.

   > A NSFetchedResultsController implementation for Realm written in Swift

I found out about RBQFetchedResultsController directly from Realm: (https://academy.realm.io/posts/migrating-from-core-data-to-realm/)